# How to set the width of a component to match the sum of 2 other components' width using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an `UIView` with 3 components: 1 `UIImageView` and 2 `UILabel`.

I want to create a size constraint (programmatically) so that `UIImageView.width = UILabel1.width + UILabel2.width`

With the visual format, it seems not possible. Using `constraintWithItem`, it seems I can only specify one component to compare my `UIImageView` with?

How can I do it? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are the two labels adjacent? Would it be sufficient to set the image view's leading edge equal to the first label's leading edge and the image view's trailing edge equal to the second view's trailing edge?

Comment: I totally forgot the leading/trailing edge options... Thanks! In my case it will work. But out of curiosity, even in the end if there aren't many cases like this, how would you do if they were not adjacent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Nico's actual situation, it works to constrain the image view's edges (leading and trailing) to the edges of the respective labels.

There's no direct way to constrain a view's width to the sum of the widths of other views. You can do it with gross hacks involving dummy views. For example, you can create a couple of invisible views. Set their widths equal to the widths of the labels. Embed them in a container view. Set up constraints like `H:|[view1][view2]|`. (You would also need vertical constraints, but those can be arbitrary.) So, the container's width is now equal to the sum of the widths of the labels. You could then constrain the image view's width to be equal to that container view.